# Removing a whole list row in Pandas Dataframe - if list contains element (in this case a card or two)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

First time posting and only been using Python for exactly 29 days - Most problems I've come across have been discussed before- but bitten off way more than I can chew with this...hopefully one of you guys can help. - should add the codes not mine, just messing with it.

It's a complicated card ranking method for Texas Holdem that uses a Dataframe to basically array all possible hands (2,598,960) of them - and gives hand/pot value etc (not important) but as you can imagine it is slow as anything. Couldn't actually use it for a card game.

I am trying to remove all the potential hands that DONT include the two cards dealt prior to the flop (though i'm sure it would take much longer). Before the code iterates through them after the flop to rank the hands.

I cannot work this out & i'm almost 100% sure this question is not answered anywhere on Google. At least not for removing a list row based on one (or two) elements:

This is the list (from a Panda Dataframe - printed).

```
                    hand    value
0   [D2, C2, D3, D4, D5]  17.0543
1   [D2, C2, D3, D4, C5]  17.0543
2   [D2, C2, D3, C4, D5]  17.0543
3   [D2, C2, D3, C4, C5]  17.0543
4   [D2, C2, C3, D4, D5]  17.0543
5   [D2, C2, C3, D4, C5]  17.0543
6   [D2, C2, C3, C4, D5]  17.0543
7   [D2, C2, C3, C4, C5]  17.0543
8   [D2, D3, C3, D4, D5]  18.0542
```

Not sure if this helps, but thought for clarity i'd provide some of the code (and comments).... try not to waste days on it like I have :)

As close as I can get to a  minimal reproducible I'm afraid!

```
import pandas as pd
from scores import combinations, combi, score_hand, hand_values, df
import numpy as np
import itertools

def build_deck():
    numbers=list(range(2,6))
    suits = ['D','C']
    deck = []
    for i in numbers:
        for s in suits:
            card = s+str(i)
            deck.append(card)
    return deck

def combinations(arr, n):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    t = np.dtype([('', arr.dtype)]*n)
    result = np.fromiter(itertools.combinations(arr, n), t)
    return result.view(arr.dtype).reshape(-1, n)

def check_two_pair(hand,letters,numbers,rnum,rlet):
    pairs = []
    cards = []
    for i in numbers:
        if numbers.count(i) == 2:
            pairs.append(i)
        elif numbers.count(i) == 1:
            cards.append(i)
            cards = sorted(cards,reverse=True)
    score = 30 + max(pairs) + min(pairs)/100 + cards[0]/1000
    return score

def check_pair(hand,letters,numbers,rnum,rlet):    
    pair = []
    cards  = []
    for i in numbers:
        if numbers.count(i) == 2:
            pair.append(i)
        elif numbers.count(i) == 1:    
            cards.append(i)
            cards = sorted(cards,reverse=True)
    score = 15 + pair[0] + cards[0]/100 + cards[1]/1000 + cards[2]/10000
    return score

    def score_hand(hand):
        letters = [hand[i][:1] for i in range(5)] # We get the suit for each card in the hand
        numbers = [int(hand[i][1:]) for i in range(5)]  # We get the number for each card in the hand
        rnum = [numbers.count(i) for i in numbers]  # We count repetitions for each number
        rlet = [letters.count(i) for i in letters]  # We count repetitions for each letter
        dif = max(numbers) - min(numbers) # The difference between the greater and smaller number in the hand
        handtype = ''
        score = 0
        if 5 in rlet:
            if rnum.count(2) == 4:
                handtype = 'two pair'
                score = check_two_pair(hand,letters,numbers,rnum,rlet)
            elif rnum.count(2) == 2:
                handtype = 'pair'
                score = check_pair(hand,letters,numbers,rnum,rlet)
        elif rnum.count(2) == 4:
            handtype = 'two pair'
            score = check_two_pair(hand,letters,numbers,rnum,rlet) 
        elif rnum.count(2) == 2:
            handtype = 'pair'
            score = check_pair(hand,letters,numbers,rnum,rlet)
        else:
            handtype= 'high card'
            n = sorted(numbers,reverse=True)
            score = n[0] + n[1]/100 + n[2]/1000 + n[3]/10000 + n[4]/100000
    # print('this hand is a %s:, with score: %s' % (handtype,score))
        return score
    
    def handvalues(combinations):
        scores =[{"hand": i, "value": score_hand(i)} for i in combi] # We iterate over all combinations scoring them # THATS THE TIME SAVING BIT THERE
        scores = sorted(scores, key = lambda k: k['value']) # We sort hands by score
        return scores
        
    deck = build_deck() # We create our deck
    combi = combinations(deck,5) # We create an array containing all possible 5 cards combinations
    hand_values = handvalues(combi)
    x = [i.get("hand","") for i in hand_values] # making a list of hands
    y = [i.get("value","") for i in hand_values] #making a list of values
    
    data = {'hand':x, 'value':y} # making a dictionary of hands and values
    df = pd.DataFrame(data) # making a pandas dataframe with hands and values
```

Don't worry I'll be heading back to learn the basic after this!

Thanks for reading

Comment: Instead of screenshots of data can you provide [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug  Did my best for you still a big file

Comment: Correct me, you want to remove row where your 'hand' matches certain hand condition right ?

Comment: Yeah - so if the dealt cards were a C2 & D5  id want to remove every row that did not contain both those cards

Comment: Hey @Sam I have posted my answer, I guess that what you want right ? any changes in it then let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get only rows which  does not contain 'C2' and 'D5' in it, then following should work. You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to iterate, and then just use conditionals. I used [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) to convert your hand array into `Series` object as it contain [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) method which was used to check if it contain 'C2' and 'D5'.

```
import pandas as pd

#Test data
data = {  
'hand':[['D2', 'C2', 'D3', 'D4', 'D5'],
        ['D2', 'C2', 'D3', 'D4', 'C5'],
        ['D2', 'C2', 'D3', 'C4', 'D5'],
        ['D2', 'C2', 'D3', 'C4', 'C5'],
        ['D2', 'C2', 'C3', 'D4', 'D5'],
        ['D2', 'C2', 'C3', 'D4', 'C5'],
        ['D2', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'D5'],
        ['D2', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'],
        ['D2', 'D3', 'C3', 'D4', 'D5'],
        ['D2', 'DX', 'C3', 'D4', 'DN']],
'value' : [17.0543,17.0543,17.0543,17.0543,17.0543,17.0543,17.0543,17.0543,18.0542,18.0523]

}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Solution(See from below)
mask = df['hand'].apply( lambda hand_arr: not pd.Series(hand_arr).isin(['C2','D5']).any())
df.loc[mask]
```

Output:

```
    hand    value
9   [D2, DX, C3, D4, DN]    18.0523
```

Comment: That works perfectly - don't think I'd have ever gotten there.- your a star! 

If I don't do whatever I should do in thanks just point me in the right direction.